# Solve equation with sum in it

Tags: equation-solving, summation

Have trouble to solve this equation.
Anybody knows where're the problems?

```
h = 663*^-36;
c = 3*^8;
k = 138*^-25;
l[λ_] :=Function[y, (2*h c^2/λ^5)/(Exp[h c/(λ k y)] - 1)];
a = Table[x, {x, 400, 700, 10}]*10^-9;
v = Rationalize[{0.0004, 0.0012, 0.0040, 0.0116, 0.0230, 0.0380, 
0.0600, 0.0910, 0.1390, 0.2080, 0.3230, 0.5030, 0.7100, 0.8620, 
0.9540, 0.9950, 0.9950, 0.9520, 0.8700, 0.7570, 0.6310, 0.5030, 
0.3810, 0.2650, 0.1750, 0.1070, 0.0610, 0.0320, 0.0170, 0.0082, 
0.0041}];
lx = l[a];
lt = lx[t]
de = Sum[lt[[k]]*v[[k]], {k, 1, 31}]
dr = Rationalize[de]
Solve[dr == 1/683*10^5, t, Reals]
```

The program will running for very long time without final output.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Table[{t, N[dr]-1/683*10^5}, {t,1,1000}] to see why Solve might be having a difficult problem. Then FindRoot[dr - 1/683*10^5, {t, 750}]

Comment: @Bill 
Thank you for your help. It worked out. But, why can't we get the result directly by using Solve command?

Comment: @Andrew Try to solve it by hand and you'll see ...

Comment: @Bill I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew If `Solve` is treating the equation as a polynomial in `E^(1/t)`, then the equation is of degree 10^20+, which is not practically feasible.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, I got the idea, thank for your explanation.

Comment: `NSolve[dr == 1/683*10^5 && 700 < t < 800, t, Reals]` works, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you will need to use a numeric technique

```
h = 663*^-36;
c = 3*^8;
k = 138*^-25;
l[λ_] := 
  Function[y, (2*h c^2/λ^5)/(Exp[h c/(λ k y)] - 1)];
a = Range[400, 700, 10]*10^-9;
v = Rationalize[{0.0004, 0.0012, 0.0040, 0.0116, 0.0230, 0.0380, 0.0600, 
    0.0910, 0.1390, 0.2080, 0.3230, 0.5030, 0.7100, 0.8620, 0.9540, 0.9950, 
    0.9950, 0.9520, 0.8700, 0.7570, 0.6310, 0.5030, 0.3810, 0.2650, 0.1750, 
    0.1070, 0.0610, 0.0320, 0.0170, 0.0082, 0.0041}];
```

I assume that you want `l` mapped onto `a`

```
lx = l /@ a;

lt = #[t] & /@ lx;

de = lt.v;
```

See [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) product

```
Plot[{Evaluate[de], 1/683*10^5},
 {t, 745, 750},
 PlotLegends -> {"de", 1/683*10^5}]
```

[image]

```
soln = FindRoot[de == 1/683*10^5, {t, 748}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

(*  {t -> 747.811927549212867608509450996}  *)

de == 1/683*10^5 /. soln

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Yeah, very helpful, kind of more clear to find the suitable interval for the FindRoot Command